# execute single line mysql with string literal

Tags: mysql, linux

I am trying to execute a single line command to connect and get a value from mysql via command line:

How can I get the mysql result without all the formatting. I dont want the ascii tables just the "2"

```
mysql --host=host --user=user --password=pass db -e 'SELECT `state` FROM `user_states` WHERE `user_id`="6fbb0740-e743-11e3-ac10-0800200c9a66"'
```

Comment: MySQL in its default configuration is happy with [string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html) in double quotes. Give it a try.

Comment: awesome that worked! now how do i get just the value returned without all the "pretty" ascii tables

Answer (score 0):

If you want it just plain use -B or [--batch](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_batch) option and deactivate the display of the column names with --column-names=0

```
mysql --host=host --user=user --password=pass --batch --column-names=0 db -e 'SELECT `state` FROM `user_states` WHERE `user_id`="6fbb0740-e743-11e3-ac10-0800200c9a66"'
```

> --batch, -B
>
> Print results using tab as the column separator, with each row on a
>   new line. With this option, mysql does not use the history file.
>
> Batch mode results in nontabular output format and escaping of special
>   characters. Escaping may be disabled by using raw mode; see the
>   description for the --raw option.
>
> --column-names
>
> Write column names in results.